# How to check for a null value in an element of a json object in node js function?

Tags: node.js, json

I am using [google-play-scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper) module in node.js to scrape google play reviews. The review function for a single page is as below:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
gplay.reviews({
  appId: 'es.socialpoint.chefparadise',
  page: 0,
  }).then(console.log, console.log);
```

Now, I like to scrape all the comments on all pages at once and save them in a logger. For this, I am using winston logger and a for loop as below:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
const winston= require('winston');

  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'rev1.log' })
   ]
  });
package_id='com.jetstartgames.chess'
for (i=0; i<112; i++){

    gplay.reviews({
    appId: package_id,
    page: i,
    }).then(logger.info, logger.info); 
}
```

The problem is that I should pre-defined the maximum number of pages that each application owns for its reviews (I should determine the maximum value of i for the loop). In order to do this, I taught of checking for the null value but I couldn't find a plausible way for doing it. The log file for a page that doesn't exist in reality has a structure as below:

{"message":[],"level":"info"}

I tried this code which doesn't work:

```
max=0
for (i=0; i<10000; i++){
 data=gplay.reviews({
    appId: 'com.jetstartgames.chess',
    page: i,
    });
    if (data.message==null || data.message==undefined){
        break;
    } else {
        max+=1;
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can figure out the maximum number of pages by checking of the first null output? or any other suggestion for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a couple issues, it looks like the api your using uses Promises so the returned value won't be available for you until further loops.

If your using a node.js > 7.6 you can you use async / await like so;

```js
import gplay from 'google-play-scraper';

async function getReviews(appId, page = 1) {
  return await gplay.reviews({
    appId,
    page,
  });
}

async function process(appId) {
  let page = 1;
  let messages = [];
  let result;

  do {
    result = await getReviews(appId, page);
    messages = messages.concat(result);
    ++page;
  } while (result.length > 0);

  return messages;
}

process('com.jetstartgames.chess')
.then((messages) => {
  console.log(messages);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using node v10.15.1. But it doesn't allow me to use the module 'asyncawait/async'. It gives me the following error: Error: Cannot find module 'asyncawait/async'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename ...

Comment: @NasirHaghighi are you trying to import it? It is part of js core and would not need to be imported

Comment: I see! I checked it without importing now and it gives me the following error: ReferenceError: result is not defined at process ....  at process._tickCallback

Comment: Still not working! TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: Looks like the module returns an array of reviews, not `result.message` like stated above? If those are what you want to collect then you would use the edited version above.

Answer (score 0):

I try to implement like this. Pls try and let me know if it works :)

In document from [reviews](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#reviews), pls noted:

> Note that this method returns reviews in a specific language (english
>   by default), so you need to try different languages to get more
>   reviews. Also, the counter displayed in the Google Play page refers to
>   the total number of 1-5 stars ratings the application has, not the
>   written reviews count. So if the app has 100k ratings, don't expect to
>   get 100k reviews by using this method.

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
    var appId = 'com.jetstartgames.chess';
    var taskList = [];

    for(var i = 1 ; i < 10000; i++){
        taskList.push(new Promise((res, rej)=>{
            gplay.reviews({
                appId: appId,
                page: i,
                sort: gplay.sort.RATING
            }).then(result =>{
                res(result.length);
            })
            .catch(err => rej(err)) 
        }));
    }

    Promise.all(taskList)
    .then(results => {
        results = results.filter(x => x > 0);
        var maxPage = results.length;
        console.log('maxPage', maxPage);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It gives me the following error: Error: Error requesting Google Play:read ECONNRESET

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I should pre-defined the maximum number of pages that each application owns for its reviews (I should determine the maximum value of i for the loop).

I think we can get this data from [`app`](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#app) response.

```
{
  appId: 'es.socialpoint.chefparadise',
  ...
  ratings: 27904,
  reviews: 11372, // data to determine pagenumber
  ...
}
```

Also, [`review`](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#reviews) offers a ball park number for the page number calculation.

> page (optional, defaults to 0): Number of page that contains reviews. Every page has 40 reviews at most.

Making those changes,

```
'use strict';

const gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
const packageId = 'es.socialpoint.chefparadise';

function getAppDetails(packageId) {
  return gplay.app({ appId: packageId })
    .catch(console.log);
}

getAppDetails(packageId).then(appDetails => {
  let { reviews, ratings } = appDetails;

  const totalPages = Math.round(reviews / 40);

  console.log(`Total reviews => ${reviews} \nTotal ratings => ${ratings}\nTotal pages => ${totalPages} `);

  let rawReview = [];

  let pageNumber = 0;
  while (pageNumber < totalPages) {
    console.log(`pageNumber =${pageNumber},totalPages=${totalPages}`);
    rawReview.push(gplay.reviews({
      appId: packageId,
      page: pageNumber,
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(packageId, pageNumber);
      console.log(err);
    }));
    pageNumber++;
  }

  return Promise.all(rawReview);
}).then(reviewsResults => {
  console.log('***Reviews***');
  for (let review of reviewsResults) {
    console.log(review);
  }
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Err ', err);
});
```

It worked well for the packageId which had less reviews. But for `es.socialpoint.chefparadise` I frequently ran into [Issue #298](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/issues/298) since the data size is huge.

**Output**

> Total reviews => 215922
>   Total ratings => 688107
>   Total pages => 5398
>   ***Reviews***
>   ....

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem is that the number of reviews which comes from "app" function is the total number of reviews (from all languages). But, the "review" function works only for one language at a time. So, the review number we get from "app" function is always greater or equal to the max we are looking for. The difference is significant for the apps with higher number of reviews.